# 8086 Assembly Language Program to find GCD of two numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32, greatest-common-divisor

Right when it hits " Ret 8" my program stops working. Would anyone be able to tell me why?

Find the GCD of 2 numbers inputted by the user. Keeps looping around till you stop it.

Thanks in advance

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc

.data

    msg1 byte " Enter first number", 0ah, 0dh,0
    msg2 byte " Enter second number",0ah, 0dh,0
    msg3 byte " GCD is ",0ah,0dh,0
    ValA DWORD ?
    ValB DWORD ?

.code

main PROC

     start:
            mov edx, offset msg1
            call WriteString
            call ReadDec
            mov ValA,eax



            mov edx, offset msg2
            call WriteString
            call ReadDec
            mov ValB,eax

            mov eax,DWORD ptr[ValA]
            mov ebx,DWORD ptr[ValB]
            push ValB
            push ValA
            call CalcGcd
            call DumpRegs
            call start

    exit
    main ENDP


CalcGcd PROC

        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        xor edx,edx
        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        mov ebx, [ebp+12]

    L1:
        cmp eax,ebx
        JE DONE
        JB EXCH

    L2:
        div ebx
        cmp edx,0
        JE DONE
        mov eax,ebx
        mov ebx,edx
        JMP L1

    EXCH:
        XCHG eax,ebx
        JMP L1

    DONE:
        mov eax,ebx
        mov edx, offset msg3
        call writestring
        call writedec
        ret 8



    CalcGcd ENDP
    END main
```

Comment: The conditional swap isn't actually necessary: another iteration of `div` will do that for you as you keep the remainder and discard the quotient.  (See [a code-golf GCD loop in 8 bytes of x86-32 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364).)  But `div` is slow enough that branching to use `xchg` instead on some iterations might actually be worth the branch mispredict penalties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is missing a `pop ebp` just before the return. The `call start` will loop over and over until the program runs out of stack space.